# Update / Insert with prepared queries doesn't persist into database

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have some problems with MySQL prepared queries. Especially UPDATE and INSERT.

```
$mysqliStmt->execute();
```

It does NOT update or insert into a table. It just delivers stmt results. There are no errors, warnings, or anything else. (See below)

The Insert query I use:

```
INSERT INTO testdatabase.`test` (`test1`, `test2`) VALUES(?, ?)
```

The Update query:

```
UPDATE testdatabase.`test` SET `test1` = ? WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1
```

Resultinformation (update):

```
'fieldCount' => 0,
'affectedRows' => 1,
'numRows' => 0,
'paramCount' => 2,
'insertId' => 0,
'sqlstate' => '00000',
'threadId' => 5291,
'errno' => 0,
'error' => '',
'warningCount' => 0,
'warnings' => false
'connectErrno' => 0,
'connectError' => NULL,
'hostInfo' => 'Localhost via UNIX socket',
'protocolVersion' => 10,
'serverInfo' => '5.1.49-3',
'serverVersion' => 50149,
'clientInfo' => '5.0.27',
'clientVersion' => 50027,
'info' => 'Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0'
```

The code:

```
$stmt = self::$_connection->prepare($query);
//binds params -> like/with $stmt::bind_param() but more generic
$this->_bindParameters($stmt) 
$stmt->execute();
```

Now the update/insert data should be stored into database or I'm wrong?

If I use phpMyAdmin or MySQL console to verify the results of the queries, the database table was neither updated nor was the new data inserted.

Comment: Is autocommit turned on?

Comment: Yes. Its turned on. 

The if i do a SELECT after the UPDATE/INSERT it will return the results of UPDATE/INSERT correctly. But it is NOT stored in the database if i check it with console or phpmyadmin.

Comment: After i checked the class again i found the problem. You were right ppeterka. Autocommit was disabled because one method set it to false and that was the error. 

Thank you very much :)